# Wrong number of iterations when BiCGSTAB called with guess

Tags: c++, solver, eigen3

I am using the c++ and Eigen library to solve a system with BiCGSTAB solver.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers>
```

At some point in the code I initialize the matrix `A` and rhs vector `rhs`

```cpp
int N = domain.size();
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> M(N, N);
Eigen::VectorXd rhs(N);
rhs.setZero();
M.reserve(storage.supportSizes());
```

Finally solver is created and system is solved

```cpp
        Eigen::BiCGSTAB<decltype(M), Eigen::IncompleteLUT<double>> solver;
        solver.setMaxIterations(300);
        solver.compute(M);
        auto sol = solver.solveWithGuess(rhs, guess);
        if (debug) {
            print(solver.iterations());
            print(solver.error());
        }
```

### Problem

The problem with the above code is that the output is unreasonable

```
solver.iterations() = 94414646480416;
solver.error() = 6.91858e-310;
```

even when the initial guess is a vector of zeros (as is the defaulty way for BiCGSTAB). I must point out here, that the the time required to solve the system is a matter of (mili)seconds, so I am quite sure it did not do the 94414646480416 iterations.

Does anybody know how to get the number of iterations when solution is obtained with a guess?

Comment: Don't use `auto` with Eigen unless you know what you are doing (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#title3). Your `auto sol = ...` line does not actually solve the system yet.

Comment: @chtz Oh wow, you are absolutely correct. If you can post this as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it. Thanks eitherway!